# Bounding Fejer kernel

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

My Ferjer kernel is defined to be $F_N(t):= \frac{1}{N+1}(\frac{sin(N+1)\pi t}{sin \pi t})^2$, I want to show that $F_N(t) \leq \frac{c}{N+1}min\{N+1, \frac{1}{x^2}\}$ on $[\frac{1}{-2}, \frac{1}{2}]$.

Thoughts: I need some kind of bound on $sin(N+1)\pi t$, but I do not see how to derive a useful bound.

Answer (score 1):

Each different book normalizes the Fourier coefficient in a different way, here is a general idea to achieve your goal. You could change the normalization, i.e. dividing some $\pi$, or $2\pi$, or translation, etc.

Firstly, $\sin n\alpha\leq n\sin\alpha$. Thus, 
\begin{align*}
|F_{N}(x)|&=\dfrac{1}{N+1}\dfrac{|\sin\frac{N+1}{2}x|^{2}}{|\sin\frac{x}{2}|^{2}}\\
&\leq\dfrac{1}{N+1}(N+1)^{2}\dfrac{|\sin\frac{x}{2}|^{2}}{|\sin\frac{x}{2}|^{2}}
\\
&=N+1,
\end{align*}
so you have your fist bound.

For the other one, you need to know the fact that $$|\sin\frac{x}{2}|\geq\dfrac{|x|}{\pi},\ \text{for}\ 0<|x|<\pi.$$

Thus, 
\begin{align*}
|F_{N}(x)|&=\dfrac{1}{N+1}\dfrac{|\sin\frac{N+1}{2}x|^{2}}{|\sin\frac{x}{2}|^{2}}\\
&\leq\dfrac{1}{N+1}\dfrac{1}{|\sin\frac{x}{2}|^{2}}
\\
&\leq \dfrac{\pi^{2}}{(N+1)x^{2}}.
\end{align*}

This gives you the second bound.

Depending on the normalization, some books will normalize the kernel by dividing either $\pi$ or $2\pi$, but you have the constant $C$, so no need to worry.

Comment: This doesn't solve the question

Comment: @Jakobian Ok i see what the problem is. Hm... I only solved it when $1/x^{2}\leq N+1$. The problem is that $1/x^{2}$ can be really large when $x$ becomes close to $0$. Hard.